# Data storing in haskell - excel like rows and cols

Tags: haskell, file-io, types

I have a following quest:

I have to write program in Haskell which will allow me to create something like excel sheet.
There are columns and rows, and each cell can hold number or string or some function (sum, mean, multiply etc). Each of the functions take as parameters a list of cells which are summed  etc.

Now I am trying to figure out how to store this data into my program...
I was thinking about something like this:

```
data CellPos = CellPos Int Int -- row and col of Cell
data DataType = Text | String | SumFunction | ...... deriving (Enum)

data Cell = Cell CellPos DataType -- but here is a problem , how to put here data with type which depends on DataType???
```

I wanted just to have big list of `Cell` and search in it for specified column/row etc

But there must be some better solution for this – maybe some two dimensional array which auto adjust its size or something?

I will have to save/load a sheet to /from file...

Answer (score 6):

Let's answer one question at a time:

```
data Cell = Cell CellPos DataType
```

"but here is a problem , how to put here data with type which depends on DataType???"

Put that data into `DataType`:

```
data DataType = Text String | Number Double | Function CellPos (DataType -> DataType)
```

"I wanted just to have big list of Cell and search in it for specified column/row etc. But there must be some better solution for this - maybe some two dimmensional array which auto adjust its size or something?"

I suggest a `Map CellPos DataType`.

"I will have to save/load a sheet to /from file..."

The simplest thing will probably be to derive `Show` and `Read` and use the resulting functions together with `readFile` and `writeFile`. The only caveat here (with respect to `DataType` as defined earlier in this answer) is that functions cannot be serialized. To get around this, make a more explicit type for the functions in cells -- perhaps an abstract syntax tree for some simple expression language.

Comment: But how I can store any data in memory and be able to change it/update and so on and only write to file on demand?

Comment: @user606521 Please open a new question here with some more concrete details. What code did you try? What did you want to happen? What happened instead? Or: what stopped you from writing the code you wanted to write?